# Estimation of Propensity Score using Random Forests

Tags: random-forest, nonparametric, causality, propensity-scores

Suppose that one has a binary treatment $Z$, and assume that $Z=1|X=x \sim Bern\left(e(x)\right)$.
Furthermore, suppose I want to estimate the propensity score by a random forest. Are there consistency and asymptotic results in this case and if so, what are the regularity conditions that are needed to achieve them?

Comment: Well usually people just use boosted models like the ones from the R-package `twang`, but following their documentation I can't even find anything about specific conditions for it to function, except checking convergence afterwards. See the Vignettes here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twang/index.html

Comment: If you have a parametric model like this, is there really a need to use a random forest?